# JAVA:SeaGlass LAF & RSyntaxTextArea Package

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel, rsyntaxtextarea

when i using SeaGlass LAF all things is ok,but when i request a page that have an object from RSyntaxTextArea Package gives me an error,i've no problem with nimbus and all thing works perfectly...
note:i use this method at the main class to changing the whole LAF of all windows of my program:

```
        try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.seaglasslookandfeel.SeaGlassLookAndFeel");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("UIManager Exception : " + e);
    }
```

and whole the program taking effect the SeaGlass LAF,can i set the LAF per each window manually and isolate the window that has an object from RSyntaxTextArea package?

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at sun.font.FontDesignMetrics$MetricsKey.init(FontDesignMetrics.java:217)
>       at sun.font.FontDesignMetrics.getMetrics(FontDesignMetrics.java:286)
>       at sun.swing.SwingUtilities2.getFontMetrics(SwingUtilities2.java:1012)
>       at javax.swing.JComponent.getFontMetrics(JComponent.java:1624)
>       at org.fife.ui.rtextarea.RTextAreaBase.updateMarginLineX(RTextAreaBase.java:1113)
>       at org.fife.ui.rtextarea.RTextAreaBase.setFont(RTextAreaBase.java:939)
>       at org.fife.ui.rsyntaxtextarea.RSyntaxTextArea.setFont(RSyntaxTextArea.java:2170)
>       at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI.installDefaults(BasicTextUI.java:307)
>       at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextAreaUI.installDefaults(BasicTextAreaUI.java:83)
>       at org.fife.ui.rtextarea.RTextAreaUI.installDefaults(RTextAreaUI.java:350)
>       at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI.installUI(BasicTextUI.java:787)
>       at org.fife.ui.rtextarea.RTextAreaUI.installUI(RTextAreaUI.java:407)
>       at javax.swing.JComponent.setUI(JComponent.java:664)
>       at javax.swing.text.JTextComponent.setUI(JTextComponent.java:338)
>       at org.fife.ui.rtextarea.RTextAreaBase.setRTextAreaUI(RTextAreaBase.java:1064)
>       at org.fife.ui.rtextarea.RTextAreaBase.init(RTextAreaBase.java:622)
>       at org.fife.ui.rtextarea.RTextAreaBase.(RTextAreaBase.java:115)
>       at org.fife.ui.rtextarea.RTextArea.(RTextArea.java:216)
>       at org.fife.ui.rsyntaxtextarea.RSyntaxTextArea.(RSyntaxTextArea.java:347)
>       at GUI.CodeEditorPage.(CodeEditorPage.java:31)
>       at GUI.StartPage.WcodeActionPerformed(StartPage.java:375)
>       at GUI.StartPage.access$900(StartPage.java:19)
>       at GUI.StartPage$10.actionPerformed(StartPage.java:162)
>       at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
>       at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
>       at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
>       at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
>       at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
>       at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
>       at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
>       at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
>       at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
>       at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
>       at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
>       at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:729)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:688)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:686)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:702)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:700)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:699)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)

Comment: at least some one says what happen to my program in this case?